# Avoid "cropped" dots in thick dotted line

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I avoid "cropped" points when drawing a thick dotted line?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,dotted] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The results is not very aesthetically pleasing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dash expand off` option might be useful for you.

From the TikZ & PGF [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

> `/tikz/dash expand off`
>
> Makes the `off` part of a dash pattern expandable such that it can stretch. This only works when there is a single `on` and a single `off` field and requires the `decorations` library. Right now this option has to be specified on the path where it is supposed to take effect after the dash pattern option because the `dash pattern` has to be known at the point where it is applied.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [dotted,dash expand off] (0,0.1) -- (1.02,0.1);
  \draw [dotted,dash expand off] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh that's a nice trick too. I didn't remember seeing that in the manual, thanks for drawing attention to it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customize dashed pattern, depending on the length of your line. Here's a simple example with no automated calculation:

[image: customized dashed pattern]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.5mm,dash pattern={on 0.5mm off 0.5mm}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```